Strange error with "Cannot form key path to main actor-isolated property ..." in Swift concurrency
I have this code:
// empty struct for demo purpose.
struct DailyRewardItem {}

@MainActor
protocol Plugin {
  var dailyRewardItems: [DailyRewardItem] { get }
}

enum MagicItemType: CaseIterable {
  case shuffle
  case hammer
  case rocket
  case bomb
  
  @MainActor
  var dailyRewardItem: DailyRewardItem {
    return DailyRewardItem()
  }
}

class MyPlugin: Plugin {
  let dailyRewardItems = MagicItemType.allCases.map(\.dailyRewardItem)
}

I got this warning:

Cannot form key path to main actor-isolated property 'dailyRewardItem'; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode

Here MyPlugin is implicitly main actor because it extends Plugin. So MyPlugin::dailyRewardItems is also main actor. The keyPath is also in main actor. Not sure why this gives warning.
If I don't use the keyPath, it is working fine without warning.
  let dailyRewardItems = MagicItemType.allCases.map { $0.dailyRewardItem }

I am using Xcode 16 beta 3, Swift 5 with "complete" concurrency checking.

This is a bug, and is fixed in this PR, merged on 2024-07-09, and is now fixed in beta 6.
From the PR description:

This allows isolated key-path components to be used in stored property initializers when the stored property itself is isolated to the same global actor.


Other than using a closure, initialising the property in init also removes the warning in the current version:
init() {
    dailyRewardItems = MagicItemType.allCases.map(\.dailyRewardItem)
}


Strange. I just tried beta 4 and the warning is still here.

@OMGPOP Does the code in the bug report still produce a warning? It could also be that the version of Swift that comes with Xcode isn't from the main branch. Try pulling the main branch and building it locally. If that still emits a warning, I'd suggest submitting another issue.

@OMGPOP In fact I think I just found another bug (I'm using Xcode 15.4), though will probably be resolved when this comes out. In this case you are passing the keypath to a non-sendable closure, so everything is fine, but if you try to pass a main actor isolated key path to a @Sendable closure, it also compiles! This only happens with key paths - if you pass { $0.dailyRewardItem } instead, the compiler correctly points out that this is an error.

I don't know how to compile swift and use it in Xcode :( but i think i will wait for beta 5

Hmmm, Xcode Beta 5 is out today and it's still not working. Are you sure it's Swift bug and not an issue with my code?

Just tried out Swift 6  and it becomes an error

@OMGPOP I’ll ask this again since you still haven't answered me. Does the code in the bug report compile now? If it still doesn't, wait for the next beta. If it does, you should file a new bug report. I am 99% sure this is a bug.

It doesn't compile after Switching to Swift 6 (tried on Xcode 16 beta 5). The same warning becomes an error complaining about "Cannot form key path to main actor-isolated property 'dailyRewardItem'".

@OMGPOP I'm not asking about your code. Try compiling the code in the bug report. Does that compile without warnings in beta 5?

Yes it compiled fine. Tried both Swift 6 and Swift 5 complete  concurrency checking. Both works without any warnings or errors.

@OMGPOP You should submit a new bug report then. In the mean time, I also found a new bug report.

This is finally fixed in Beta 6
